# Reduce space between author note title and main body using APA6 package

Tags: spacing, apa6

I would like to have true double-spacing between Author Note title, and the rest of the text (e.g., *Corresponding author in the following example).

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,noextraspace,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Title of the Study}
\authornote{*Corresponding author:

Funding sources: 

Conflict of interest: 

Ethics approval: }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,noextraspace,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\shorttitle{Title}
\title{Title of the Study}
\author{An author}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\authornote[1]{\long\def\@acks{\vspace*{-\topskip}#1}}
\makeatother
\authornote{*Corresponding author:

Funding sources: 

Conflict of interest: 

Ethics approval: }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Than you so much!